# Getting the value of a property of a class in a class

Tags: c#, reflection

Ok so I have been up and down the internet looking for a solution to this question.  I think my title is maybe no to informative so some background.

I have the following classes:

```
public class foo { public string Name { get; set; } }
public class foo1 { public string Name { get; set; } }
public class foo2 { public string Name { get; set; } }
public class foo3 { public string Name { get; set; } }
public class foo4 { public string Name { get; set; } }
public class foo5 { public string Name { get; set; } }

public class goo 
{ 
   public string Desc { get; set; }
   public foo f { get; set; }
   public foo1 f1 { get; set; }
   public foo2 f2 { get; set; }
   public foo3 f3 { get; set; }
   public foo4 f4 { get; set; }
}
```

So now my question,  Using Reflection, how can I get to the value of foo.Name when only having a reference to goo.

The normal Reflection code is:

```
goo g = new goo();
PropertyInfo pInfo = g.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
string Name = (string)pInfo.GetValue(g, null);
```

So the above code is how you get a property from the goo class.  But now how do you get the value of foo.Desc?

I tried the following which doesn't work:

```
goo g = new goo();
PropertyInfo pInfo = g.GetType().GetProperty("f");
PropertyInfo pInfo2 = pInfo.PropertyType.GetProperty("Desc");
string Name = (string)pInfo2.GetValue(pInfo.PropertyType, null);
```

Unfortunately I get a Mismatched object error which I can understand because I am trying to use the property type and not the actual instance of the foo class.  I also tried to fins a way to instantiate an object from the propertyinfo but if there is a way then it eludes me.  I could do something like this:

```
goo g = new goo();
PropertyInfo propInfo = g.GetType().GetProperty("f");
object tmp;

propInfo.SetValue(g, Convert.ChangeType(new foo(), propInfo.PropertyType), null);
tmp = g.f;
```

This works but besides having to hard code the class, that is creating a new instance and therefore of now use to me.

As I say I have been up and down looking for a solution.  Everything I have found is basically variants on the "get a value of a property of a class" theme but nothing about going another level deeper.

Can anyone help?  Is this even possible because I would really like to stay away from hard coding.

EDIT: I have edited the class to more accurately represent what I am working with.  Based on the comments below, I am getting the names of the foo instances from a database and that is why I am using Reflection or want to use Reflection instead of hard coding 30+ switch statements.

EDIT: Also I don't know before runtime which foo classes will be populated with data.  Also each foo class is different.  Unlike my example where each foo class has a string property, in my project each class has a different design which mirrors the database.

EDIT:  So Ulugbek Umirov gave the answer.  I just didn't see it immediately.  Below my implementation so as to maybe help others in the future.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in _standard.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (_fullDataModel.ClassDefinitions.Contains(pInfo.Name))
    {
        PropertyInfo _std_pinfo = _standard.GetType().GetProperty(pInfo.Name);
        object g = _std_pinfo.GetValue(_standard, null);

        PropertyInfo props = g.GetType().GetProperty("showMe");
        bool showMe = (bool)props.GetValue(g, null);

        if (showMe)
        {
            string tblName = _fullDataModel.ClassDefinitions[pInfo.Name].                   PropertyGroupDefinitions.Where(p => p.TransactionsTable != true).First().Token;

            //  Use tblName to build up a dataset
        }
    }
}
```

This does exactly what I wanted.
Thank you.

Comment: When foo is public, why do want to use reflection? You can simply access goo instance's foo objects and get its value.

Comment: What @Robert said is right. If Foo and Goo are public your can just access the property by using `GooInstance.FooProperty.Name`.

Comment: Besides that: what value should be in that property, if the class has not been instanciated yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current code you can do the following:

```
goo g = new goo();
g.f = new foo { Name = "Hello" };

PropertyInfo pInfo = g.GetType().GetProperty("f");
object f = pInfo.GetValue(g);
PropertyInfo pInfo2 = f.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
string name = (string)pInfo2.GetValue(f);
```

You can set arbitrary property as well:

```
goo g = new goo();

PropertyInfo pInfo = g.GetType().GetProperty("f");
object f = Activator.CreateInstance(pInfo.PropertyType);
PropertyInfo pInfo2 = f.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
pInfo2.SetValue(f, "Hello");
pInfo.SetValue(g, f);
```

Comment: Thanx.  While this doesn't answer my posted question (my fault for not adding enough info at the beginning), your 2nd bit of code helps me refine my get data call to the database and I can remove some switch statements and use CreateInstance instead.

Comment: Actually.  Apologies.  This actually solved my problem I just didn't see it immediately.  I can't believe I missed using GetValue to get an instance of the object.  Talk about needing a fresh pair of eyes.  I posted my code as an edit so you can see how I incorporated your suggestion and maybe for others that have a similar question.